# Subtracting line of a column with other line values using python 3.5?

Tags: python

```
1  10.00
2  11.23
3  12.32
4  23.55
5  15.33
6  12.23
7  22 
8  10.33
9  8.9
10 5.89
```

I have a dat file with above values. I want to subtract line 1 of column 2 with line 2,3,4...10 of column 2, then line 2 of column 2 with line 3,4,5...10, then 3 with 4,5..10 and so on until line 9 with 10. Also I would like to print the values and which line number subtracted by which? How can I do that in python? Could you please help me? I tried with numpy but could not figure out solve it with my conditions. 
I will really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Store the values into a list, then operate on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
k = [10.0, 11.23, 12.32, 23.55, 15.33, 12.23, 22, 10.33, 8.9, 5.89]
k[:] = [x - 10.0 for x in k]

[0.0, 1.23, 2.32, 13.55, 5.33, 2.23, 12.0, 0.33, -1.1, -4.11]
```